# Convert data frame to spatial object and find the polygon that contains a point

Tags: r, geospatial, point-in-polygon

I have two data frames. The first contains the longitude and latitude coordinates for a series of locations. And it looks like this:

[image: df1]

The second data frame contains gridded data, the head is as follows. The longitude range is (-10.70, -5.35) and the latitude range is (51.33, 55.38).

[image: df2]

I need to find the grid that contains the value of each city given in data frame 1. Do I need to convert it to a spatial object or is it possible to do it directly from the data frames? How can I do that?

Comment: Hi @aa3ls, it would be easier to help you if you could make your example reproducible. For this, it would be helpful to copy-paste the results of `dput(dataframe1)` and `dput(dataframe2)` into your question. Thanks in advance. Cheers.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Rather than edit this question, I made a new question that is much more clear.  Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71371331/find-point-on-grid-in-r)